# Can I run Cloud Automation (azure/aws) for web apps in background and performing other tasks?

Tags: testing

my goal is to automate some tests for a web app and in parallel do some other staff manually (like writing code locally or research or writing reports) and don't collide with it. I used softwares like Ginger, Power Automate Desktop but i'm not able to do anything else until the automation is done otherwise it's interrupted. The RPA works as if it is me. It takes control of the computer it's running on.
I was thinking of moving on cloud automation by using Azure or AWS in order to run the automation initiating from my device and in parallel to do other staff.

**Tried**: Ginger, Power Automate Desktop but i'm not able to do anything else until the automation is done otherwise it's interrupted. The RPA works as if it is me. It takes control of the computer it's running on.

**Expectation**: automation of tests AND do other staff without colliding on same device with the result to do as much work as possible.

Comment: This is an interesting question. This sort of thing is generally done on a dedicated machine that runs as close to the production environment as is feasible to ensure the tests are as complete as possible. While it's suboptimal, would it be feasible to have the RPA run inside a VM or a Docker container? This would allow for a clean separation of processes. In addition to process isolation, the container could also be configured to share certain directories on your machine so that code changes locally will be immediately reflected in the testing container 